# Example of realpath function in C

Tags: c, posix, realpath

I'm looking for an example of how to use the realpath function in a C program. I can't seem to find one on the web or in any of my C programming books.

Answer (score 32):

- Note

  - The `realpath()` function is not described in the C Standard

    - It is however described by [POSIX 1997](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/realpath.html) and [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html).
- Sample Code

```c
#include <limits.h> /* PATH_MAX */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[PATH_MAX]; /* PATH_MAX incudes the \0 so +1 is not required */
    char *res = realpath("this_source.c", buf);
    if (res) { // or: if (res != NULL)
        printf("This source is at %s.\n", buf);
    } else {
        char* errStr = strerror(errno);
        printf("error string: %s\n", errStr);

        perror("realpath");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Reference

  - PATH_MAX defined in [PATH_MAX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) from [POSIX 1997](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/limits.h.html)
  - [errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)
  - [strerror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)

Comment: PATH_MAX is the maximum length for a path.  It is a weird gizmo; there is guaranteed to be a value _POSIX_PATH_MAX which is the minimum value that PATH_MAX may be.  However, many systems have a `<limits.h>` that does not set PATH_MAX, meaning there isn't a prescribed limit for the maximum length of a path on the machine.  It can also be file-system dependent, anyway.  So, you can look up a value with sysconf(), or with pathconf(), or you can take a guess that most sane people don't use paths longer than 1024 bytes and use that.

Comment: you should take into consideration calling `free(res);` after calling `realpath` and finishing from `res`. As `realpath` allocates the return value in the heap. Source: `man realpath`

Comment: @JalalMostafa: POSIX `realpath()`, as described in the link in my answer, does not allocate memory. I suspect your system is not POSIX compliant. Calling POSIX compliant `realpath()` with `NULL` for the 2nd argument invokes **UB**.

Comment: @JalalMostafa: There is a new version of the POSIX specification ([`realpath()` in POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html)) there the 2nd argument can be NULL and then `malloc()` is called. In my example, the buffer is a local array, so no cause for calling `free()`. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5):

### One-line build command line

Minimalist but it does the job!

**Build**

```
gcc -o realpath -x c - <<< $'#include<stdlib.h>\n#include<stdio.h>\nint main(int c,char**v){puts(realpath(v[1],0));}'
```

**Test**

```
$> ./realpath  ~/../../../usr/./bin/./awk
/bin/gawk 

$> readlink -f ~/../../../usr/./bin/./awk
/bin/gawk
```

**Requirements**

- [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) for compilation and link
- [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) for `<<<` and `$' ...  \n  ... '`

**Crash**

My minimalist one-line command line builds an executable `realpath` that produces a `Segmentation fault` when the path does not exist. Instead of writing `if`/`else` blocs to handle that issue within my answer, I have added below some links to let you have a look on the Busybox implementation of `realpath` and `readlink`.

---

### Busybox implementation

For a more complete source code, have a look on this simple implementation.

**Official Git repository**

- [`coreutils/realpath.c`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/realpath.c)
- [`coreutils/readlink.c`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/readlink.c)
- [`libbb/xreadlink.c`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/libbb/xreadlink.c)

**GitHub mirror repository**

- [`coreutils/realpath.c`](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/realpath.c)
- [`coreutils/readlink.c`](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/readlink.c)
- [`libbb/xreadlink.c`](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/libbb/xreadlink.c)

Comment: /usr/bin/readlink -f does not require the path exist. However, realpath api does. Could you help to comment how to mimic readlink in this respect ?

Comment: Hi @SOUser. Thank you for your feedback. You are right, my minimalist one-line command line builds an executable `realpath` that produces a **`Segmentation fault`** when path does not exist. Instead of writing `if/else` blocs to handle that within my answer, I have added links to let you have a look on the Busybox implementation of `realpath` and `readlink`. I hope you appreciate the Busybox source code. Please let me know if I can help. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

What the `realpath()` function does is tell you the absolute pathname of a file when all symbolic links have been resolved.

You may have a 'realpath' program already on your machine.  Here's the (non-standard) version I wrote.

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: realpath.c,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 1.3 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2007/10/23 20:23:44 $
@(#)Purpose:        Command to evaluate realpath(3) on given arguments.
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Copyright:      (C) JLSS 2007
@(#)Product:        :PRODUCT:
*/

/*TABSTOP=4*/

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static const char optstr[] = "hlsV";
static const char usestr[] = "[-hslV] given-path [...]";
static const char hlpstr[] =
    "  -h   Print this help message\n"
    "  -l   Long format: print given-path and real-path\n"
    "  -s   Short format: print just real-path\n"
    "  -V   Print version and exit\n"
    ;

enum { FMT_LONG, FMT_SHORT };
static int format_type = FMT_LONG;

#ifndef lint
/* Prevent over-aggressive optimizers from eliminating ID string */
extern const char jlss_id_realpath_c[];
const char jlss_id_realpath_c[] = "@(#)$Id: realpath.c,v 1.3 2007/10/23 20:23:44 jleffler Exp $";
#endif /* lint */

static int eval_realpath(const char *given)
{
    char realname[_POSIX_PATH_MAX];
    int rc = 0;

    if (realpath(given, realname) == 0)
    {
        rc = -1;
        err_sysrem("failed to resolve real path name for %s\n", given);
    }
    else if (format_type == FMT_SHORT)
        printf("%s\n", realname);
    else
        printf("%s %s\n", given, realname);
    return(rc);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    int opt;

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'V':
            err_version("REALPATH", &"@(#)$Revision: 1.3 $ ($Date: 2007/10/23 20:23:44 $)"[4]);
            break;
        case 'h':
            err_help(usestr, hlpstr);
            break;
        case 'l':
            format_type = FMT_LONG;
            break;
        case 's':
            format_type = FMT_SHORT;
            break;
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (eval_realpath(argv[i]) != 0)
            rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return(rc);
}
```

I needed it to test some software that was evaluating the security of a path, and needed to be sure my code was evaluating the given path to the same resolved location as `realpath()` does.  It would probably be sensible to extend it with a '-a' option to ensure names are mapped to absolute names (by prefixing the result of `getcwd()` to relative pathnames).

(The extra source code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c`, `stderr.h` and `errhelp.c` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.)

Comment: No, it *does* necessarily give you an absolute path name.  [The documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realpath.html) says "The *realpath()* function shall derive, from the pathname pointed to by *file_name*, an absolute pathname that names the same file, ..."

Comment: That's odd; you're right, yet...I must have gotten the wrong idea from somewhere.  The difficulty almost four years after writing the code, and most of two years after writing the answer, is knowing where I got the misinformation from.  It will take some investigation on obscure systems.

Comment: Hi there. It's 2022. Trying to understand your answer. I do  `gcc -g -Wall  reallink1.c stderr.c stderr.h` it  won't compile. The error is `undefined reference to `err_help'` / @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @Mark: Apologies — you will need `errhelp.c` too , which is available from my SOQ repository, as documented in the tail of the question.  If there's another non-standard file you need, the source/header should be in the same directory of the repository.  If something is missing altogether, please let me know.