# How to get absolute path of a symbolic link?

Tags: c, linux

How can I get the absolute path of a symbolic link? If I do it in the following way:

```
char buf[100];
realpath(symlink, buf);
```

I won't get the absolute path of the symlink, but instead I would get the absolute path this symlink links to. Now my question is: What If I want to get the absolute path of the symlink itself? Is there any function in Linux C that allows me to do so?

Note: What I'd like to achieve is the absolute path of the symbolic link itself, not the path it's pointing to! For example, if the relative path of a symbolic link is `Task2/sym_lnk`, I want its absolute path, which can be `/home/user/kp/Task2/sym_lnk`.

Comment: This is OS specific. (The standard library has no notion of symbolic links.) Linux? Then label it as such.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017500/how-to-see-full-symlink-path. IT suggests trying `readlink`

Comment: @shapiroyaacov While that question targets the command line it probably points in the proper direction since there exists a glibc function of the same name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [following symbolic links in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569402/following-symbolic-links-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You can use realpath() function with the parent folder of the symlink, then you concatenate the symlink name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Find the last occurrence of c in str, otherwise returns NULL
char* find_last_of( char *str, char c )
{
    for( char *i = str + strlen(str) ; i >= str ; i-- )
        if( *i == c )
            return i;
    return NULL;
}

// Does the job
char* getAbsPath( char *path  )
{
    char *name; // Stores the symlink name
    char *tmp; // Aux for store the last /
    char *absPath = malloc( PATH_MAX ); // Stores the absolute path

    tmp = find_last_of( path, '/' );

    // If path is only the symlink name (there's no /), then the
    // parent folder is the current work directory
    if( tmp == NULL ){ 
        name = strdup( path );
        getcwd( absPath, PATH_MAX ); // Is already absolute path
    }
    else{
        // Extract the name and erase it from the original
        // path.
        name = strdup( tmp + 1 );
        *tmp = '\0';
        // Get the real path of the parent folder.
        realpath( path, absPath );
    }
    // Concatenate the realpath of the parent and  "/name"
    strcat( absPath, "/" );
    strcat( absPath, name );
    free( name );
    return absPath;
}

// Test the function
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    char *absPath;

    if( argc != 2 ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Use:\n\n %s <symlink>\n", *argv );
        return -1;
    }
    // Verify if path exists
    if( access( argv[1], F_OK ) ){
        perror( argv[1] );
        return -1;
    }

    absPath = getAbsPath( argv[1] );
    printf( "Absolute Path: %s\n", absPath );
    free( absPath );
    return 0;
}
```

If you use the above code with directories, it needs an special case for "." and "..", but works with "./" and "../"

Comment: The standard function equivalent to `find_last_of()` is `strrchr()`.  Note that if the character sought is not in the string, the code in `find_last_of()` decrements `i` (an unusual name for a `char *` variable) to before the start of the array.  That is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the system call `readlink()`:

```
int readlink(const char* fdpath, char* filepath, size_t pathsize);
```

`fdpath` is the `path` of the symbolic link, something like `/proc/pid/fd/link_number`.

`filepath` is the path of the file it's pointing to.

Note that `readlink()` does not null terminate the output string, but does reports its length in the return value.

Comment: how can i determine the last argm '256'? How can I know the length of filepath beforehand?

Comment: @Kindermann, in my project what i did was take a big enough string to fit any path. Unless its some ridiculously long [path, i think you will do good with 256 or 512

Comment: @Kindermann: "how can i determine the last argm '256'?" see `PATH_MAX` constant from `limits.h`

Comment: @Haris, can you have a look at my Note above. I wanted to get the abs path of the symbolic link itself, but filepath is the path of the file its pointing to...are they the same?

Comment: @Kindermann: Alternatively, use a dynamically allocated buffer, and call `readlink` in a loop; as long as `readlink` keeps returning the same value as `bufsiz`, you `realloc` the buffer (increasing by multiples or by some fixed number of bytes at a time) and try again. When the return doesn't match the `bufsiz`, manually insert the `NUL` at the return value's index (because `readlink` doesn't do it for you) and you're done. To test, start with a small `bufsiz` so you can verify you expand correctly.