# Printing Symbolic Link to corresponding file

Tags: c

I was wondering how would one be able to print filenames like below in C while the -> represents a symbolic link to the corresponding file?

```
Makefile
bar -> foo
bar1 -> foo
bar2 -> foo
bar3 -> foo
```

Thanks!

Comment: [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink). It even contains an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get absolute path of a symbolic link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494416/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-a-symbolic-link)