# How to get directory of exec files of any commands on terminal in C?

Tags: c, unix, directory, execv, realpath

I am rewriting the problem since it's not clearly understood as far as I see. I implement my own shell in C which needs to support all commands the original one does.

The problem is to *execute all existing UNIX bash commands in C* **without** using `execvp()` or `system()` functions which already let you do that easily.

To do that, I need to search all required directories which may consist any kind of UNIX commands. I just want to know that:

Do I really be sure that I support all possible UNIX commands in any distribution when I checked all directories in my `PATH` environment variable? *(which becomes `/bin/`, `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/local/bin` in my machine)*

I have also found a method which gets the full directory of a file you inserted called [realpath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563168/example-of-realpath-function-c-programming/) . But unfortunately, it returns `(null)` when I attempt to get the directory of the command inserted in my own shell.

What else do you suggest me to achieve this problem? As a last solution, does it make sense to search whole computer recursively from the root to find the command inserted?

If there's something unclear, please let me know to clarify. I would be very thankful if you could answer with a piece of example code and clear [on hold] tag in the question if you think it's clearly described from now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean to look for files reachable with the `PATH` directory list env. variable.

Comment: hint: `/bin` is in the `PATH` system variable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you suggest me to look for the contents of the PATH env. variable? If so, can I be sure that all possible UNIX commands are located only in PATH system variable?

Comment: Are you looking for `find /`? Or `find / -exec {} \;`

Comment: @alk indeed, I expect user to input an existing unix command and try to find its executable file to be able to run that using execv function. By the way, I'm not allowed to use any other kind of exec functions such as execvp or so.

Comment: Why "*not allowed*"?

Comment: Because it's a homework at college which we are requested not to do it in easier way, I guess :) @alk

Comment: "*do I need to recursively look for the command specified from the root on my own?*" I'd say so, yes.

Comment: What you could also try 1st is to read out the `PATH` environment variable (using `getenv()`), parse the result, and check all paths in there.

Comment: But: "*can I be sure that all possible UNIX commands are located only in PATH system variable?*" no, you cannot be sure.

Comment: You need to define your problem a bit better. In most operating systems' environment  there is a variable similar to `PATH`. This variable the user has set, or has been set for the user, to contain the directories in which the system will look for executable files. The system will *only* look in these directories, it will *not* search all directories. Searching all directories for an executable is a *significant security risk*. You need to verify *exactly* what your assignment is: are you *really* supposed to search all directories, or only directories in the user's `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `realpath()` doesn't search anything, it just determines the absolute path of a given file.

There is no **all possible UNIX command** as you may think. At least any executable file can be considered as UNIX command, and executables are not necessarily the ones that have `x` right attached to it. Shell scripts may be executed by command like `sh myscript` even if executable access is not granted on it. Only binaries necessitate to have that attached right to be executed natively. So there is no true criterion that can help you. But you may have files that have `x` right and that are not executables!

A common usage is that executables are located in some directories `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, and alike. Your shell has an environnement variable named `PATH` that contains list of directories where to search for command you specified freely on command line.

Anyway, if you choose a criterion to make an exhaustive search by yourself, say all files with `x` right then you can use command `find` like `find some_starting_dir -perm +0111` to get all files that have `x` right somewhere.

If you want to program it then you may use either legacy `readdir()` function or the newer `nftw()` to make your own directory traversal. You will find many example of these even on SO.

Comment: "*But you may have files that have x right and that are not executables!*" which I'd consider to have a broken file mode.

Comment: I quoted your answer on the opposite of what your comment refers to.

Comment: @alk Oh, I apologize for my mistake...

Answer (score 3):

It is true that a UNIX executable can be absolutely anywhere, but in the context of a homework assignment, it doesn't make sense to search the entire filesystem.  What your instructor probably wants you to do is implement the functionality of `execvp` yourself, using `execv`.  What `execvp` does is, first, it looks to see if there is a slash in the command name.  If there is, it passes the command and arguments directly to `execv` - it doesn't search.  Otherwise, it iterates over the directories in `PATH` and checks whether the command is an executable in each.  Crucially, it does NOT scan the contents of each directory; not only would that be very slow, it wouldn't even work under some conditions (such as a directory with --x permissions) Instead, it blindly calls `execv` with the pathname "$dir/$cmd".  If that works, `execv` doesn't return.  If it didn't work, and `errno` is set to `ENOENT`, it goes on to try the next directory in the path.